# "Actualmente" vs. "ahora"

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

Both translate as now. How does one decide which one to use in which context? My understanding is that **ahora** is more like "right now, at this moment" whereas **actualmente** has a broader sense such as "during these times" or "nowadays." Is my understanding correct or even close? Consider the following sentences:

> 1. I'll home any time now.
> 2. She wanted to go out right now.
> 3. The country is at war with its neighbor now.
> 4. It will be four years now (since I last saw her).
> 5. Music is more ubiquitous now than it was a century ago.

I think we will use **ahora** with 1 and 2 and **actualmente** with the rest (3, 4, and 5). Am I right?

Comment: I think that, independently of the language you're speaking, it all depends on the amplitude that occurs **in the context** of the idea of "nowadays". May be synonymous or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are completely right that `actualmente` translates better as "nowadays" than "now".

Regarding the examples I think that you are almost right but number four should use `ahora`.

> It will be four years now (since I last saw her). Hará ahora cuatro años (*que no la* veo o *desde la última vez que la vi*).

First two should use `ahora` and three and five are better suited for `actualmente` but you could use `ahora` too, and convey the same meaning. Take into account that both [*actualmente*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=actualmente) and [*ahora*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=MI3f10iCCDXX2voaUUYL) mean

> En el tiempo presente.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my intuition. This is one of those cases where I don't know the exact rules and let my hunches guide me instead. Should be a good sign as far as my Spanish learning goes, I guess. ;)

Comment: How would you use *ahora* in example 1? Even though I can't understand it completely because there is at least one word missing, I would usually translate *any time now* as *en cualquier momento*.

Comment: @Gorpik, "Llegaré a casa ahora mismo"?. I think that ["any time now"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32919/what-does-the-saying-any-time-now-really-mean) means "ya mismo; ahora mismo; enseguida".

Comment: OK, that's a fair translation.

Answer (score 1):

For me `actualmente` fits better in "nowadays".

For your sentences keep in mind the use of "por el momento" or "en este instante".

As:

> I'll be/get home any time now. (Estaré en casa **en instantes**)